# htaccess redirect rule for Centos for two condition within same path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link that require https for admin access , but within one link under /admin need to be http and all other /display to be http.

example below

```
http will force  all http://example.intra/display
```

if I go to this link

```
http://example.intra/ (or http://example.intra/admin )
```

will force redirect to

```
https://example.org/admin
```

however for link below I want to force redirect to http

if go to this link

```
https://example.org/display
```

force to

```
http://example.intra/display
```

if go to this link

```
https://example.org/admin/xxxx/view/
```

I try to redirect

```
http://example.intra/admin/xxxx/view/
```

- this does not work please help

Below is the .htaccess file that I've created

````
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On```

# Condition for all admin using https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/view/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ```https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI}``` [R=301,L]
# Condition for all example.org using https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) ```https://example.org%{REQUEST_URI}``` [R=301,L]
# force http:// for selected URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/view/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ```http://example.intra%{REQUEST_URI}``` [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule !^(ui/|index.php|favicon.ico) - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
````

Comment: _“if go to this link `https://example.org/admin/xxxx/view/` I try to redirect `http://example.intra/admin/xxxx/view/`”_ - above you said you wanted to redirect everything below /admin/ to HTTPS, now it is the other way around? Please clarify.

Comment: Redirecting a client from an https based session to a http resource is not really possible. This will _always_ result in a major interruption for users: every modern browser will visualize a massive warning and suggest to the user _not_ to follow that redirection. For obvious reasons.

Comment: If I may correct the statement everything under example.org/admin to be https except for example.org/admin/xxxx/view/ . I actually have an apps that require http for viewing purposes only

Comment: my plan is to rediect example.org/admin/xxxx/view/  and use example.intra/admin/xxx/view as http . both is the same ip